# EC2(AWS)のインスタンスを再起動すると「ページが動作しません」

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws, nginx, amazon-ec2

Ruby On Railsで運用していたstaging環境をAWSのEC2からインスタンスを再起動すると、chromeで該当のURLを開こうとしても「このページは動作していません」となり、開けません。safariなど他のブラウザで開いても同じようなメッセージが出ます。

---

**環境**

macOS High Sierra(バージョン10.13.6)
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin17]
Rails 4.2.6
chrome バージョン: 71.0.3578.98（Official Build） （64 ビット）

---

**試したこと**

・ df -hでデータ容量を確認してみましたが空きは十分にありました。
・ redisを再起動してみましたが「ページが動作しません」は変わりません。
・ EC2のインスタンスを確認したところ、Elastic IPやIPv4 パブリック IPは変更されていませんでした。
(これはconfig/deploy/staging.rbやconfig/environments/staging.rbに設定されているIPアドレスと同じものです。)

・ ログを確認してみたところ、
1. nginx.access.logとnginx.error.logは動作していませんでした
2. unicorn.logとsidekiq.logとstaging.logはデプロイしたときログを吐いていますがエラーはありません。

---

**実現したいこと**

staging環境が開けなくなった原因を突き止めて、復旧したいです。
ご教示いただけることがあれば何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/167076

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まずはnginx, unicorn, sidekiqのプロセスが起動しているか確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

以下はプロセス一覧からgrepをかけてunicornプロセスが起動しているかを確認する例です。

`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep unicorn`

これで何も表示されなければunicornプロセスが起動されてないので、`bundle exec unicorn <必要なオプション>`で起動する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep nginxやps aux |grep nginx |grep -v greのコマンドを打ったところ、なにも返ってきませんでした。

Comment: unicornとsidekiqのプロセスは起動しているようです。
nginxを起動させる必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: nginxが起動してなさそうですね！

念の為、以下のコマンドでもnginxプロセスを確認してもらっても良いですか。
`systemctl status nginx.service`

Comment: `systemctl start nginx.service`

でnginxを起動できるかと。

Comment: 自分の環境にはsystemctlが入ってなかったようで、
sudo /usr/sbin/nginxを打つと起動させることができました！
本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 今後インスタンスを再起動した際に同じことが起こらないように、nginxを自動起動するようにしておくこともお勧めします。 systemctlがないので、chkconfigでできたかと…

Comment: ご親切にありがとうございます！sudo nginx -s quitでプロセスを停止してからsudo chkconfig --add nginxしてからsudo chkconfig nginx onをしましたが、nginxのプロセスがうごいてないようでした。何か不足があるのでしょうか？

Comment: おそらく`chkconfig nginx on` しただけでは次回再起動時にnginxプロセスを自動起動する、という設定にしかならないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: sudo /usr/sbin/nginxでプロセスを起動させてからsudo chkconfig --add nginx、sudo chkconfig nginx onで自動起動できました！実際にインスタンスを再起動させてみましたが、うまくできているようです。ご丁寧に有難うございました！今後ともよろしくお願いいたします！